# How do I extract a date range from a csv using perl/php/grep/etc?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, grep

Is there a way to take text like below (if it was already in an array or a file) and have it strip the lines with a specified date range?

For instance if i wanted every line from 2009-09-04 until 2009-09-09 to be pulled out (maybe this can be done with grep?) how would I go about doing so?

```
date,test,time,avail
2009-09-01,JS,0.119,99.90
2009-09-02,JS,0.154,99.89
2009-09-03,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-04,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-05,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-06,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-07,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-08,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-09,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-10,SWF,0.177,99.90
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This solution is in PHP -- but you can probably do that directly from the command-line, I suppose, with somekind of grep or anything)*

Considering your dates are in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, and that they are at the beginning of each line, you just have to compare the lines alphabetically to compare the dates.

One solution would be to :

- load the string
- explode it by lines
- remove the first line
- iterate over the lines, keeping only those that interest you

For the first parts :

```
$str = <<<STR
date,test,time,avail
2009-09-01,JS,0.119,99.90
2009-09-02,JS,0.154,99.89
2009-09-03,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-04,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-05,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-06,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-07,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-08,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-09,SWF,0.177,99.90
2009-09-10,SWF,0.177,99.90
STR;
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
unset($lines[0]); // first line is useless
```

And, to iterate over the lines, filtering in/out those you want / don't want, you could use a foreach loop... Or use the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function, which exists just for this ;-)

For instance, you could use something like this :

```
$new_lines = array_filter($lines, 'my_filter');
var_dump($new_lines);
```

And your callback function would be :

```
function my_filter($line) {
    $min = '2009-09-04';
    $max = '2009-09-09';
    if ($line >= $min && $line <= $max) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And, the result :

```
array
  4 => string '2009-09-04,SWF,0.177,99.90' (length=26)
  5 => string '2009-09-05,SWF,0.177,99.90' (length=26)
  6 => string '2009-09-06,SWF,0.177,99.90' (length=26)
  7 => string '2009-09-07,SWF,0.177,99.90' (length=26)
  8 => string '2009-09-08,SWF,0.177,99.90' (length=26)
```

Hope this helps ;-)

If your dates where not in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, or not at the beginning of each line, you'd have to [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) the lines, and use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) *(or do some custom parsing, depending on the format)*, and, then, compare timestamps.

But, in your case... No need for all that ;-)

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Python

```
import csv
import datetime

start= datetime.datetime(2009,9,4)
end= datetime.datetime(2009,9,9)

source= csv.DictReader( open("someFile","rb") )
for row in source:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date'],"%Y-%m-%d")
    if start <= dt <= end:
        print row # depends on what "pulled out" means
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could probably *somehow* make it work with grep, but sed is more suited for the task:

```
sort < file.csv | sed -ne /^2009-09-04/,/^2009-09-09/p
```

Answer (score 1):

awk solution is similar to sed:

```
awk '/^2009-09-04/,/^2009-09-09/ {next} {print}' filename
```

Without hardcoding the dates:

```
awk -v start='^2009-09-04' -v stop='^2009-09-09' '
    $0 ~ start, $0 ~ stop {next}
    {print}
' date.data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [perl's flip flop](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/06/18/variables.html) to extract a line range.

Answer (score 0):

Using [R](http://www.r-project.org)

```
> d <- read.csv("http://dpaste.com/88980/plain/", sep=",", header=T)
> r1 <- rownames(d[d$date == "2009-09-04",])
> r2 <- rownames(d[d$date == "2009-09-09",])
> d[rownames(d) %in% r1:r2,]
        date test  time avail
4 2009-09-04  SWF 0.177  99.9
5 2009-09-05  SWF 0.177  99.9
6 2009-09-06  SWF 0.177  99.9
7 2009-09-07  SWF 0.177  99.9
8 2009-09-08  SWF 0.177  99.9
9 2009-09-09  SWF 0.177  99.9
>
```

Comment: Do you see an R tag? Do you see an accepted answer? Do you see how old this question and every answer but yours is?

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

> ```
> perl -F/,/ -ane '
>     print if $F[0] ge "2009-09-04"
>           && $F[0] le "2009-09-09"' filename
> ```